# Why surfaceChanged called twice?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm playing video using SurfaceView on android, when I change the ratio from 16:9 mode to 4:3 mode, I found that the surfaceChanged callback is called twice, which means the process was completed in two steps: first, the re-sized picture was moved to the left side of the screen, then it was centered at the center of the screen. This caused a tremor of the picture when the transition took place.

Comment: Is the video content changing size, or just the output window?

Comment: Video content does not change its size, the output window size is changed, using LayoutParams:               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams()
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
mSurfaceViewRoot.setLayoutParams(lp);